# Does truncating table refresh materialized view on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Just need to make sure before truncating a table, will all data on materialized view that depend on that table wiped too?

Also if materialized view recreated (dropped and created again) after inserts happened on that table, will old rows of the source table present on the materialized view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a materialized view reflects all DDL, including `TRUNCATE` and events before the view is created.  That's easily tested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.test (X INT64 NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO temp.test (X) VALUES (1);
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW temp.view_test AS SELECT X FROM temp.test;
SELECT X FROM temp.view_test;  -- One record returned

TRUNCATE TABLE temp.test;
SELECT X FROM temp.view_test;  -- Zero records returned

INSERT INTO temp.test (X) VALUES (1);
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW temp.view_test;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW temp.view_test AS SELECT X FROM temp.test;
INSERT INTO temp.test (X) VALUES (2);
SELECT X FROM temp.view_test;  -- Two records returned
```